# how to debug javascript errors on IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, internet-explorer-8

I am getting an error, when running a webpage on IE8.  When I click on the error found, it says:

[image]

How can I go to this line to see where the error is happening?

I can't see this error on any other browser.

Also, it says:

> line 109213803.

I don't understand this, as obviously I don't have so many lines of code.

Can someone explain what IE8 is telling me here?

Comment: Open the Developer Tool (hit F12) and find out! (Probably just because IE is being IE.)

Comment: @Haochi - i dont understand . .hitting f12 does not go to this line

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Make sure script debugging is not disabled for IE, otherwise it should allow you to debug the script directly:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

IE8 has a default built-in IE Developer tool, you can use that to debug that.  Hit F12 it will open the Dev Toolbar then click the Script Tab and Start Debugging, then refresh your page. That's it!

[image: IE8 Developer Toolbar]

Answer (score 2):

Try using the Developer tools found under the tools menu. There is a script tab that will allow you to debug. You can also get there by hitting the F12 key.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to hide all js errors in IE the use this code

```
window.onerror = function(){return true;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try using the Javascript Debugger that is built in to IE8. You can access it by going to Tools > Developer Tools and click script and start to debug.

To see more, [check this out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has also made available a free toolkit called [Visual Web Developer Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/) that's a pretty comprehensive IDE for web development.